# Decipher stack-trace in React production build with componentDidCatch

Tags: reactjs, webpack, error-handling, redux

I'm using `componentDidCatch` to catch rendering errors in my app and made a component that prints stack trace provided by this hook.

However, in a production build, I see that component names are not preserved except those provided by libraries `withRouter` or `connect`. How can I achieve the same? I would like to see actual component names.

[image]

I have `source-map` enabled in webpack while building, and it's actually used by chrome:

[image]

Alternatively, I would like to decipher `componentStack` provided by componentDidCatch with source-maps. Otherwise, it's quite useless.

Comment: are you using a `.map` files?

Comment: @Sag1v yes I do.

Comment: i doubt it is related to react directly, its more related to the source map imho

Comment: @Tomasz Did you find solution? Having the same problem...

Comment: @MelvynHills unfortunately not.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js

Comment: did you guys find any solution ?

Comment: Did you try using this plugin? https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-react-displayname